# Default first letter uppercase in UIAlertController

Tags: ios, swift

Is there a way to default the first letter to **uppercase** when I display a `UIAlertController`?

```
var alertController = UIAlertController(title: i18nEnterPersonName, message: nil, preferredStyle: .Alert)
// initialization of alertController...
presentViewController(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Comment: Use capitalizedString with your string

Comment: But do you know how to display it in the UIAlertController?

Answer (score 2):

Do it like this:

```
 let alertMessage = "i18nEnterPersonName".capitalizedString
 var alertController = UIAlertController(title: alertMessage, message: nil, preferredStyle: .Alert)
```

if i18nEnterPersonName was variable (I thought it was a string), then do this:

```
 var alertController = UIAlertController(title: i18nEnterPersonName.capitalizedString, message: nil, preferredStyle: .Alert)
```